# Cardinality of Infinite Sets in a Cartesian Product

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I'm trying to show that $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2<1\}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ have the same cardinality.

It has been given to me that for any finite interval (open or closed), it has the same cardinality as the reals. Hence, it would be nice for me to use something like: $|A \times B|=|C \times D|$ if $|A| = |C|$ and $|B|=|D|$.

I highly doubt that this holds true for uncountable cardinalities. My approach to this question is to show $|\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}|=|[0, 1) \times [0, 2 \pi )|$ which will then allow me to use the $r$ and $\theta$ way to create a one-to-one relation to the open unit disk.

Any help is appreciated, and so is any criticism. Thank you very much.

Comment: The relation is indeed true. Given bijections $f:A\to C$ and $g:B\to D$, there is a very natural way to define a bijection between $A\times B$ and $C\times D$. I'll leave you to think about it. There is really only one natural way to define it. Be careful though, the unit disk is not exactly a cartesian product. If $r=0$ then all points of the form $(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$ will be the same. Your idea is good, but you need to change it a bit.

Comment: I have now changed up the relationship. I split out a {0}x{0} for the center point and the rest was changing a closed interval to an open one.

I get how the bijections can be done now. Thanks